# SprintingAnimation:19: Expected ')' (to close '(' at column 29), got ','

Tags: lua, roblox

In my game I've made a feature where you can sprint.
I've separated the animation part of the script from the main sprinting part.
I got the error message `"Workspace.Vlo_tz.SprintingAnimation:19: Expected ')' (to close '(' at column 29), got ','".`
This code is for the animation of the character and the sprinting bar

```
local UIS = game:GetService('UserInputService')
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Character = Player.Character
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local stamina = players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.StaminaHealth.MainFrame.Stamina

UIS.InputBegan:connect(function(input)
    local humanoid = Player.Character.Humanoid
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift and humanoid:GetState() == Enum.HumanoidStateType.RunningNoPhysics and humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude > 0 then
        local Anim = Instance.new('Animation')
        Anim.AnimationId = 'rbxassetid://05168161960'
        PlayAnim = Character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(Anim)
        PlayAnim:Play()

        while true do
            wait(0.05)

            if stamina.Position <= (-0.343, 0, 0.274, 0) then
                stamina.Position = UDim2.new(-0.343, 0, 0, 0)
            else
                stamina.Position = stamina.Position - UDim2.new(0.01, 0, 0, 0)
            end
        end
    end
end)

UIS.InputEnded:connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        PlayAnim:Stop()

        while true do
            wait(0.005)

            if stamina.Position >= (0.487, 0, 0.274, 0) then
                stamina.Position = UDim2.new(0.487, 0, 0, 0)
            else
                stamina.Position = stamina.Position + UDim2.new(0.01, 0, 0, 0)
            end
        end
    end
end)

local humanoid = Player.Character.Humanoid
if humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude == 0 then
    PlayAnim:Stop()

    while true do
        wait(0.005)

        if stamina.Position >= (0.487, 0, 0.274, 0) then
            stamina.Position = UDim2.new(0.487, 0, 0, 0)
        else
            stamina.Position = stamina.Position + UDim2.new(0.01, 0, 0, 0)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 19 is this : `if stamina.Position <= (-0.343, 0, 0.274, 0) then`

You have this check in a few different places, but this is not valid lua and you cannot compare UDim2 values like this. You'll have to inspect the values individually.

```
local isLessThanX = stamina.Position.X.Scale <= -0.343
local isLessThanY = stamina.Position.Y.Scale <= 0.274
if isLessThanX and isLessThanY then
```

Comment: But this isn't a great way to handle these checks either. You should have your stamina value based on some number that you can compare against, and your UI should be based on that value.

Comment: I did follow this answer but when adding the 

"local isLessThanX = stamina.Position.X.Scale <= -0.343
local isLessThanY = stamina.Position.Y.Scale <= 0.274"


I got the error Workspace.Vlo_tz.SprintingAnimation:8: Unexpected Unicode character: U+2028. Did you mean ' '?

Comment: @Vlo_tz, U+2028 is a line separator. I'm not sure how it got into my answer, maybe there was an issue with how the newlines were added in the code block. I would suggest that you just erase the code block and retype it in your script.